# Double .git folders

Tags: git, git-clone, git-init

Assume a remote repo which filesystem is a folder, say `MyRepo`, that contains other folders, say `A1, A2` and `A3`, and assume that those folders contains a bunch of files that I am tracking. Assume that I want to clone such a repo in `C:\Foo` , where `Foo` is a folder. I move into `C:\Foo`, run `git init` thus obtaining `C:\Foo\.git` folder. Then, I `clone` obtaining

```
C:\Foo\.git
C:\Foo\MyRepo
C:\Foo\MyRepo\.git
C:\Foo\MyRepo\A1
C:\Foo\MyRepo\A2
C:\Foo\MyRepo\A3
```

I have two .git folders. My questions are

1. Is that possible to remove `C:\Foo\.git`?
2. In general, does the location of the .git folder makes difference? For example, if I overwrite `C:\Foo\.git` with `C:\Foo\MyRepo\.git` would that create problems?

Comment: If you are cloning a repo, you don't need to `init` beforehand. You can delete the `C\Foo\.git` without touching the `MyRepo` repository.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Is that possible to remove C:\Foo.git?

Possible in the sense that you'll lose all information that was in the git metadata in `Foo\.git`. But I think that you didn't want `Foo` to be git repo in the first place. Just don't run `git init` on `Foo`.

> 2. In general, does the location
>      of the .git folder makes difference?

Of course!

> For example, if I overwrite
>   C:\Foo.git with C:\Foo\MyRepo.git would that create problems?

Yes, the paths that git stores information to would be changed.

I think this question reflects your lack of understanding what a git repo actually is, I recommend starting with a simple tutorial like [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control).